# "error: expected expression before 'do'" when wrapping macro-based library

Tags: cython

I want to wrap a library that gives me dynamic arrays at C-speeds. For this I have found https://troydhanson.github.io/uthash/utarray.html

It works in C, but when I do a port of a simple example to Cython, it does not work.

```
# src/array_test.pyx

cimport src.array as cn

import numpy as np

def main():

    cdef cn.UT_array *found
    cn.utarray_new(found, &(cn.ut_int_icd))

    cdef long[::1] indexes = np.array(range(10, 20), dtype=np.long)

    for i in range(10):

        cn.utarray_push_back(found, &(indexes[i]))

    cn.utarray_free(found)

    return
```

The error messages are:

```
./src/utarray.h:76:29: error: expected expression before 'do'
 #define utarray_new(a,_icd) do {                                              \
                             ^
src/array_test.c:1973:10: note: in expansion of macro 'utarray_new'
   (void)(utarray_new(__pyx_v_found, (&ut_int_icd)));
```

(and the same for utarray_push_back and utarray_free).

The definitions file:

```
# src/array.pxd

cdef extern from "src/utarray.h":

    ctypedef struct UT_icd:
        pass

    ctypedef struct UT_array:
        pass

    const UT_icd ut_int_icd

    UT_array utarray_new(UT_array *a, UT_icd *icd)
    utarray_len(UT_array *a)
    int* utarray_eltptr(UT_array *a, int j)
    utarray_push_back(UT_array *a, void *p)
    utarray_free(UT_array *a)
```

Here is my setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from setuptools import find_packages, Extension, Command
from Cython.Build import cythonize

extensions = [Extension("src.array_test", ["src/array_test.pyx"])]


setup(
    name = "uthash",
    packages=find_packages(),
    ext_modules = cythonize(extensions),
    package_data={'': ['*.pyx', '*.pxd', '*.h', '*.c']},
    include_dirs=["."],
)
```

And finally, the C library, all contained in a header file:

```
# src/utarray.h

/*
Copyright (c) 2008-2018, Troy D. Hanson   http://troydhanson.github.com/uthash/
All rights reserved.
Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
    * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
      notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS
IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED
TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT OWNER
OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL,
EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO,
PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR
PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF
LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING
NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS
SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
*/

/* a dynamic array implementation using macros
 */
#ifndef UTARRAY_H
#define UTARRAY_H

#define UTARRAY_VERSION 2.0.2

#include <stddef.h>  /* size_t */
#include <string.h>  /* memset, etc */
#include <stdlib.h>  /* exit */

#ifdef __GNUC__
#define UTARRAY_UNUSED __attribute__((__unused__))
#else
#define UTARRAY_UNUSED
#endif

#ifndef oom
#define oom() exit(-1)
#endif

typedef void (ctor_f)(void *dst, const void *src);
typedef void (dtor_f)(void *elt);
typedef void (init_f)(void *elt);
typedef struct {
    size_t sz;
    init_f *init;
    ctor_f *copy;
    dtor_f *dtor;
} UT_icd;

typedef struct {
    unsigned i,n;/* i: index of next available slot, n: num slots */
    UT_icd icd;  /* initializer, copy and destructor functions */
    char *d;     /* n slots of size icd->sz*/
} UT_array;

#define utarray_init(a,_icd) do {                                             \
  memset(a,0,sizeof(UT_array));                                               \
  (a)->icd = *(_icd);                                                         \
} while(0)

#define utarray_done(a) do {                                                  \
  if ((a)->n) {                                                               \
    if ((a)->icd.dtor) {                                                      \
      unsigned _ut_i;                                                         \
      for(_ut_i=0; _ut_i < (a)->i; _ut_i++) {                                 \
        (a)->icd.dtor(utarray_eltptr(a,_ut_i));                               \
      }                                                                       \
    }                                                                         \
    free((a)->d);                                                             \
  }                                                                           \
  (a)->n=0;                                                                   \
} while(0)

#define utarray_new(a,_icd) do {                                              \
  (a) = (UT_array*)malloc(sizeof(UT_array));                                  \
  if ((a) == NULL) oom();                                                     \
  utarray_init(a,_icd);                                                       \
} while(0)

#define utarray_free(a) do {                                                  \
  utarray_done(a);                                                            \
  free(a);                                                                    \
} while(0)

#define utarray_reserve(a,by) do {                                            \
  if (((a)->i+(by)) > (a)->n) {                                               \
    char *utarray_tmp;                                                        \
    while (((a)->i+(by)) > (a)->n) { (a)->n = ((a)->n ? (2*(a)->n) : 8); }    \
    utarray_tmp=(char*)realloc((a)->d, (a)->n*(a)->icd.sz);                   \
    if (utarray_tmp == NULL) oom();                                           \
    (a)->d=utarray_tmp;                                                       \
  }                                                                           \
} while(0)

#define utarray_push_back(a,p) do {                                           \
  utarray_reserve(a,1);                                                       \
  if ((a)->icd.copy) { (a)->icd.copy( _utarray_eltptr(a,(a)->i++), p); }      \
  else { memcpy(_utarray_eltptr(a,(a)->i++), p, (a)->icd.sz); };              \
} while(0)

#define utarray_pop_back(a) do {                                              \
  if ((a)->icd.dtor) { (a)->icd.dtor( _utarray_eltptr(a,--((a)->i))); }       \
  else { (a)->i--; }                                                          \
} while(0)

#define utarray_extend_back(a) do {                                           \
  utarray_reserve(a,1);                                                       \
  if ((a)->icd.init) { (a)->icd.init(_utarray_eltptr(a,(a)->i)); }            \
  else { memset(_utarray_eltptr(a,(a)->i),0,(a)->icd.sz); }                   \
  (a)->i++;                                                                   \
} while(0)

#define utarray_len(a) ((a)->i)

#define utarray_eltptr(a,j) (((j) < (a)->i) ? _utarray_eltptr(a,j) : NULL)
#define _utarray_eltptr(a,j) ((a)->d + ((a)->icd.sz * (j)))

#define utarray_insert(a,p,j) do {                                            \
  if ((j) > (a)->i) utarray_resize(a,j);                                      \
  utarray_reserve(a,1);                                                       \
  if ((j) < (a)->i) {                                                         \
    memmove( _utarray_eltptr(a,(j)+1), _utarray_eltptr(a,j),                  \
             ((a)->i - (j))*((a)->icd.sz));                                   \
  }                                                                           \
  if ((a)->icd.copy) { (a)->icd.copy( _utarray_eltptr(a,j), p); }             \
  else { memcpy(_utarray_eltptr(a,j), p, (a)->icd.sz); };                     \
  (a)->i++;                                                                   \
} while(0)

#define utarray_inserta(a,w,j) do {                                           \
  if (utarray_len(w) == 0) break;                                             \
  if ((j) > (a)->i) utarray_resize(a,j);                                      \
  utarray_reserve(a,utarray_len(w));                                          \
  if ((j) < (a)->i) {                                                         \
    memmove(_utarray_eltptr(a,(j)+utarray_len(w)),                            \
            _utarray_eltptr(a,j),                                             \
            ((a)->i - (j))*((a)->icd.sz));                                    \
  }                                                                           \
  if ((a)->icd.copy) {                                                        \
    unsigned _ut_i;                                                           \
    for(_ut_i=0;_ut_i<(w)->i;_ut_i++) {                                       \
      (a)->icd.copy(_utarray_eltptr(a, (j) + _ut_i), _utarray_eltptr(w, _ut_i)); \
    }                                                                         \
  } else {                                                                    \
    memcpy(_utarray_eltptr(a,j), _utarray_eltptr(w,0),                        \
           utarray_len(w)*((a)->icd.sz));                                     \
  }                                                                           \
  (a)->i += utarray_len(w);                                                   \
} while(0)

#define utarray_resize(dst,num) do {                                          \
  unsigned _ut_i;                                                             \
  if ((dst)->i > (unsigned)(num)) {                                           \
    if ((dst)->icd.dtor) {                                                    \
      for (_ut_i = (num); _ut_i < (dst)->i; ++_ut_i) {                        \
        (dst)->icd.dtor(_utarray_eltptr(dst, _ut_i));                         \
      }                                                                       \
    }                                                                         \
  } else if ((dst)->i < (unsigned)(num)) {                                    \
    utarray_reserve(dst, (num) - (dst)->i);                                   \
    if ((dst)->icd.init) {                                                    \
      for (_ut_i = (dst)->i; _ut_i < (unsigned)(num); ++_ut_i) {              \
        (dst)->icd.init(_utarray_eltptr(dst, _ut_i));                         \
      }                                                                       \
    } else {                                                                  \
      memset(_utarray_eltptr(dst, (dst)->i), 0, (dst)->icd.sz*((num) - (dst)->i)); \
    }                                                                         \
  }                                                                           \
  (dst)->i = (num);                                                           \
} while(0)

#define utarray_concat(dst,src) do {                                          \
  utarray_inserta(dst, src, utarray_len(dst));                                \
} while(0)

#define utarray_erase(a,pos,len) do {                                         \
  if ((a)->icd.dtor) {                                                        \
    unsigned _ut_i;                                                           \
    for (_ut_i = 0; _ut_i < (len); _ut_i++) {                                 \
      (a)->icd.dtor(utarray_eltptr(a, (pos) + _ut_i));                        \
    }                                                                         \
  }                                                                           \
  if ((a)->i > ((pos) + (len))) {                                             \
    memmove(_utarray_eltptr(a, pos), _utarray_eltptr(a, (pos) + (len)),       \
            ((a)->i - ((pos) + (len))) * (a)->icd.sz);                        \
  }                                                                           \
  (a)->i -= (len);                                                            \
} while(0)

#define utarray_renew(a,u) do {                                               \
  if (a) utarray_clear(a);                                                    \
  else utarray_new(a, u);                                                     \
} while(0)

#define utarray_clear(a) do {                                                 \
  if ((a)->i > 0) {                                                           \
    if ((a)->icd.dtor) {                                                      \
      unsigned _ut_i;                                                         \
      for(_ut_i=0; _ut_i < (a)->i; _ut_i++) {                                 \
        (a)->icd.dtor(_utarray_eltptr(a, _ut_i));                             \
      }                                                                       \
    }                                                                         \
    (a)->i = 0;                                                               \
  }                                                                           \
} while(0)

#define utarray_sort(a,cmp) do {                                              \
  qsort((a)->d, (a)->i, (a)->icd.sz, cmp);                                    \
} while(0)

#define utarray_find(a,v,cmp) bsearch((v),(a)->d,(a)->i,(a)->icd.sz,cmp)

#define utarray_front(a) (((a)->i) ? (_utarray_eltptr(a,0)) : NULL)
#define utarray_next(a,e) (((e)==NULL) ? utarray_front(a) : ((((a)->i) > (utarray_eltidx(a,e)+1)) ? _utarray_eltptr(a,utarray_eltidx(a,e)+1) : NULL))
#define utarray_prev(a,e) (((e)==NULL) ? utarray_back(a) : ((utarray_eltidx(a,e) > 0) ? _utarray_eltptr(a,utarray_eltidx(a,e)-1) : NULL))
#define utarray_back(a) (((a)->i) ? (_utarray_eltptr(a,(a)->i-1)) : NULL)
#define utarray_eltidx(a,e) (((char*)(e) >= (a)->d) ? (((char*)(e) - (a)->d)/(a)->icd.sz) : -1)

/* last we pre-define a few icd for common utarrays of ints and strings */
static void utarray_str_cpy(void *dst, const void *src) {
  char **_src = (char**)src, **_dst = (char**)dst;
  *_dst = (*_src == NULL) ? NULL : strdup(*_src);
}
static void utarray_str_dtor(void *elt) {
  char **eltc = (char**)elt;
  if (*eltc != NULL) free(*eltc);
}
static const UT_icd ut_str_icd UTARRAY_UNUSED = {sizeof(char*),NULL,utarray_str_cpy,utarray_str_dtor};
static const UT_icd ut_int_icd UTARRAY_UNUSED = {sizeof(int),NULL,NULL,NULL};
static const UT_icd ut_ptr_icd UTARRAY_UNUSED = {sizeof(void*),NULL,NULL,NULL};


#endif /* UTARRAY_H */
```

Comment: My guess is that the error is due to utarray.h not being compiled. It looks like this: https://github.com/troydhanson/uthash/blob/master/src/utarray.h If this is the case, how do I turn it into the .c file I need?

Comment: The example should be reproducible, but is there a way to make the files even easier to dl and test for you people?

Comment: An untested guess: these macros don't return anything but you've told Cython that they either return `UT_array`, or it's assumed they return a `PyObject*` (which I think is what it assumes if you leave out the return type). Try telling it that they return `void`

Comment: The easiest way to share complicated multi-file examples like this is to create a repo on github that we can clone.

Comment: @ngoldbaum Thanks, that was that I was thinking, but then I am not anonymous anymore XD But I guess I can live with people knowing I ask inane questions

Comment: @DavidW Yes, you nailed it. Perhaps write that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to declare the "functions" to Cython as if the have a void return type

```
void utarray_new(UT_array *a, UT_icd *icd)
# ... 
void utarray_push_back(UT_array *a, void *p)
void utarray_free(UT_array *a)
```

`utarray_new` definitely doesn't return a `UT_array`. I *think* Cython assumes a `PyObject*` return type for the cases where you don't declare it. In any case, it is generating code to "handle" the returned value that it's expecting and that `do {} while` loops don't provide. Telling it that these macros return nothing avoids this.

---

(Answer ends here... the rest of this is just a small moan about the approach that the library you're using has taken.)

Excessive use of macros (or their more advanced relative inline functions) can often be counterproductive. Function calls are actually pretty quick, and so for anything even slightly non-trivial you can often lose speed due to the cost of having to load extra (duplicated everywhere) code. Modern compilers are pretty good at making their own judgements about when to inline.

On top of this, you have a whole lot of definitions that look like a function, but have subtle differences from a function. For example, the following C code would be valid for a function, but a disaster with a macro:

```
UT_array* a[5]; // 5 long array of UT_array*s
UT_array* ai = a[0]; // pointer to first element
for (int i=0; i<5; ++i) {
    utarray_new(ai++,some_icd_value); // "new" current ai, increment in preparation for next iteration
}
```

Therefore, the all-macro header probably hasn't gained any speed, may actually have lost some speed, and has caused the program to have a range of non-obvious bugs that would not happen with function calls.

Obviously this is a choice that the library writer, rather than you, has made.

Comment: Thanks for the rant. I am still new to C. I was surprised that the speedup from python lists (in cython) was minimal. Perhaps that is one reason.

Comment: Python lists would probably be a bit slower, but numpy arrays + Cython should end up pretty close to "C speed", so I wouldn't look for alternative array libraries (unless they provide a really useful feature that you're missing)

Comment: I might have to manually resize the numpy arrays. Also a source of bugs